# How to call RESTAPIs in magento2.2.4?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.4

Currently I am using `magento2.2.4`. How to call REST APIs in magento?

Is there magento2 provide default REST APIs?  and how can I call the rest apis?

Comment: Can this help you? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/gs-web-api-request.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Magento 2.2.4 provides REST API for all the functionalities like customers, products, orders, wishlist, etc.,

First, you need to get a token to access these REST APIs. For that you may use this API: http://www.domainname.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token and your payload should have admin access username and password. Refer this screenshot: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/images/gs_auth_token1.png

You will receive a token and you can use this token to use on all your API calls.

Here is the list of APIs available in Magento 2 (listed by Module): 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html

Comment: How can i use it?  Can you give a small example.

Comment: To create a mobile app for your store, you will need to create a mobile app and call these APIs. For instance, if user chooses login button, you can call the user login API and pass the username and password entered.

Answer (score 1):

This is the core PHP way to call APIs

```
<?php
$userData = array("username" => "adminUserName", "password" => "AdminPassword");
$ch = curl_init("BaseUrl/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);



$ch = curl_init("BaseUrl/rest/V1/customers/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));


$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Below is the complete list of API by default provided by magento

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html

Answer (score 0):

> Open the System > Extensions > Integrations

[image]

> Add New Integration

[image]

> Set the integration **Name** and other settings, then specify your
>   Magento 2 back-end password in the **Your Password** field

[image]

> Switch to the **API** sidebar tab and select the resources which will
>   be available to **OAuth clients**:

[image]

> Press the **Save** button. The **integration** will be saved and the
>   **Integrations** list will be shown again. Press the **Activate** link in the integration row:

[image]

> A confirmation screen will be shown. Press the **Allow** button

[image]

> The credentials screen will be shown.
>     Use them in your third-party software to access your Magento 2 as OAuth server.
>
> **You will see:**
>
> - Consumer Key
> - Consumer Secret
> - Access Token
> - Access Token Secret
>
> Copy it to somewhere, then press the **Done** button.

[image]

> The integration will be saved and the **Integrations** list will be
>   shown again. You will see your integration in the **Active** state:
>   [image]

---

and for Customer Token

In magento web-API when you pass user name and password then it genrates token for that specific customer (Which is only valid for 1 hour - configurable from admin)

> http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=test.user@test.com&password=test@123

**webapi.xml code**

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

**which returns token.**

After genrating token, when we pass that token in header.

```
Authorization :: Bearer <Token Value>

http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me
```

Which returns customer detailes.

The above case i explained is working fine for webAPI in magento2 which i tested in **POSTMAN**.

Comment: Yepp, let me know if stuck anywhere

Comment: how can i get login api

Comment: how can i get authorization header

Comment: do you have POSTMAN ?

Comment: yes i have post man.could you connect my team viewer or skype

Comment: run this http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=test.user@test.com&password=test@123

Comment: using your customer mail and password

Comment: this is my host url:http://www.depoto.com/Beta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81313/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-nukala-satish).